# Using "Alternate Tier 1" in Apple In-App Purchases

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I am developing an app for a Swedish client and want to implement the In-App Purchase. In the app we will sell credits. Price of credit should be 99 SEK. So I selected "Alternate Tier 1". Now when I try to purchase credit, it shows the price in USD that is 0.99 USD as default. My problem is: how can I change it to Swedish currency 99 SEK?

I request product details like this.

```
- (void)requestProductsWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers {
    _productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                        initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    _productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [_productsRequest start];
}
```

I receive price in USD, I am wondering how can I get price in SEK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The price that's shown is dependent on the country that your iTunes account is set to. You can create test users in iTunes Connect so you can try it out yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My issue is when I request product list it returns with USD not SEK. I have edited My question.

Comment: The currency returned depends on the iTunes Store that your user is signed in to. If you're logged into the Swedish store you'll get SEK; the British store GBP; and the American store USD. If they're not logged in it probably doesn't matter since they won't be able to buy anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use an NSNumberFormatter and set it with the locale you get from the SKProduct.priceLocale use it to format the string to show the price to the user.